# Started a thread named MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager cleanup but has failed to stop it

Tags: java, tomcat, amazon-web-services

I am writing a web application using Amazon Web Services AWS Java SDK. Apache commons HttpClient version 3 is used behind the scenes. I have commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar included.

I have the following warning in my catalina.out

```
SEVERE: The web application [/MyAppName] appears to have started a thread named
[MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager cleanup] but has failed to stop it. This is 
very likely to create a memory leak.
```

So I wrote a ServletContextListener with contextDestroyed() method calling:

```
MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.shutdownAll();
```

However, the warning still shows, despite the method is been called. What else should I do to ensure cleanup?

**EDIT**: I wanted to be absolutely sure that contextDestroyed() was indeed called (on suggestion of nos), so I placed a breakpoint on the first statement of the method, stopped the server and the breakpoint got hit I executed the method step by step to be sure that exceptions are not raised, and every line of the method was executed without problem. Here is my source code:

```
@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
    System.out.println("contextDestroyed() start");
    MyMemCache.shutDown();
    MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.shutdownAll();
    ClassLoader contextClassLoader=Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    LogFactory.release(contextClassLoader);
    java.beans.Introspector.flushCaches();
    System.out.println("contextDestroyed() end");
}
```

When hot swapping:

```
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/MyAppName] has started
contextDestroyed() start
contextDestroyed() end
05 24, 11 3:11:00 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader 
    clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/MyAppName] appears to have started a thread 
    named [MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager cleanup] but has failed to 
    stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure your contextDestroyed() gets called ?

Comment: put try catch in the contextDestroyed method.

Comment: Ok, I am adding a try catch for **Exception**, and print the stack trace. However, If an exception was raised the string "contextDestroyed() end" would not be printed. I will update if anything gets caught...

Comment: The update is: I added the try/catch, I went on developing on other things, went through many redeployments and I never saw an exception thrown in that method.

Comment: Actually listener with MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.shutdownAll();
 did the work for me. The thread was closing correctly..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating to AWS Java SDK version 1.2.1 solved the problem. This version was not available yet when I posted the question, since it was released on May 26, 2011.

AWS SDK 1.2.* uses HttpClient 4, released in 2009, but AWS Java SDK was still using version 3 in its 1.1.* versions. I won't go in further details to analyze their code changes since my problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in the AWS SDK where they open two HttpClients and only shut down one of them.
My problem is slightly different in that I want to start and stop clients for various regions and accounts without restarting the webapp.

I've worked around the issue (which I have reported to them but they do not seem inclined to fix) with:

```
public class MyAmazonEC2Client extends AmazonEC2AsyncClient {
    private boolean shutdownCalled = false;


    public MyAmazonEC2Client(final AWSCredentials awsCredentials) {
        super(awsCredentials);
    }


    public MyAmazonEC2Client(final AWSCredentials awsCredentials, final ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration) {
        this(awsCredentials, clientConfiguration, Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
    }


    public MyAmazonEC2Client(
                                 final AWSCredentials awsCredentials,
                                 final ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration,
                                 final ExecutorService executor) {
        super(awsCredentials, clientConfiguration, executor);
    }


    /**
     * Shuts down this client object, releasing any resources that might be held open.<br />
     */
    @Override
    public synchronized void shutdown() {
        try {
            shutdownCalled = true;

            // Call the proper shutdown method. This is in the base type and only shuts down one of the HttpClients created (the one that's never used)
            super.shutdown(); // close the HttpClient in AmazonWebServiceClient
        }
        finally {
            // Fix a bug in Amazon's implementation where they've duplicated the HttpClients
            try {
                super.client.shutdown(); // close the HttpClient in AmazonEC2Client
            }
            catch (Throwable t) {
                // ignore failures
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: very interesting. thanks. I'm going to experiment with it later today.

Comment: I tried with and the warning is still there. I don't understand why you say "they open two HttpClients and only shut down one of them". All of those classes are descendants of AmazonWebServiceClient which contains HttpClient client (one instance) and the shutdown() method calls client.shutdown(), so with your implementation you call the same method two times on the same Object. Correct me if I'm wrong. On a side note I saw that AWS SDK 1.2.1 is out and uses HttpClient 4, I'll have to change a bit of my code to use that. Do you think that the bug would be still there with this new version?

Comment: In the JavaDoc of shutdown() "Shuts down this client object, releasing any resources that might be held open. This is an optional method, and callers are not expected to call it, but can if they want to explicitly release any open resources. Once a client has been shutdown, it should not be used to make any more requests." -- However, it doesn't get called automatically too, because if I put a breakpoint there it doesn't get hit.

I could hold all the references in my Factory, and then loop on them, but that would prevent garbage collection for them.

Comment: Ah yes, I assumed you were calling shutdown() from your code.
In the version of the SDK this is based on there are actually two HttpClients with different visibility, super.shutdown() shuts down one but not the one which is visible through super.client... I'll have a look at sdk 1.2.1, thanks for the info :-)

Answer (score 0):

I got similar error in axis2 web service also, and found it was a [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/i#browse/AXIS2-4898) in axis which is fixed in axis2 1.6 version.

Although this question is answered for AWS but i have put my answer for guys who are looking for similar error of axis2.