# Seeking a method to Catch and Debug "Couldn't stop Thread" Occurences

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, jetty-9

I have a test program doing load testing on a HTTP server.  It is using some simple Jetty HttpClient code to do a HTTP GET using HttpClient.**send**().  In the log, every now and then we see this message - Could be an error or an exception:

- "**Couldn't stop Thread**", e.g. (truncated for readability):

  ```
   [24412925] INFO  2014-Sep-03 23:20:12.967>  -- Request:  "http://server.url/getstring ...  
   [24413187] WARN  2014-Sep-03 23:20:13.229> HttpClient@692613741{STOPPING,8<=0<=200,i=0,q=0} Couldn't stop Thread[HttpClient@692613741-304742,5,]
   [24413187] INFO  2014-Sep-03 23:20:13.229>  -- Response #30,473, 00:00:00.262 = [ 22.8K received (max: 102.6K ): "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><message ..."
  ```

As you see the message comes after the HTTP GET was received.  There was no Exception caught (because they are ALL logged) and the XML string received is intact.

I want to catch or detect this problem, and perhaps prevent it.  The questions or interest at present are:

1. Can we catch or detect this problem at run-time in the calling code?

   - Is there a way to monitor activity on the Jetty HttpClient code's threads?
2. What does it mean?

   - Is there a way to get some diagnostics onto this message/event?
3. Can we kill the Jetty HttpClient processing programmatically to clear-up this kind of thing?

   - I'm asking because at the end of the day this script needs to run unattended.  So if we can't use a Try/Catch exception handling approach, the second best approach is to ensure ALL internal state is cleared/clean.
4. Is this something specific to Linux?

   - So far, we've seen this on *both* Linux and on Windows running the same JAR.

I am hoping this is a curiosity.  However at the same time, on general principles, library should be able to provide some information either as an exception or with a status-code on things like this.  I cannot afford to have unexplained thread problems for a unattended mode or operation.  Hope one of you has a way to manage or deal with this one, thanks in advance.

***similar questions***:

- [Jetty: Stopping programatically causes "1 threads could not be stopped"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650713/jetty-stopping-programatically-causes-1-threads-could-not-be-stopped)
- [Started a thread named MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager cleanup but has failed to stop it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099425/started-a-thread-named-multithreadedhttpconnectionmanager-cleanup-but-has-failed)
- [server does not shut down promptly on CTRL-C (SIGINT)](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/issues/490) (HitHub error)
- [Solr and Jetty deployment issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14056785/solr-and-jetty-deployment-issue)
- BugZilla issue: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=357318 ... Perhaps this message is a response to a bug like this.  Was something fixed or is it a mysterious message?

***Jetty source***:

One location for this message though not really explaining the cause or network state.

- http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/xref/org/eclipse/jetty/util/thread/QueuedThreadPool.html (Lines: 170-190, approx.)

Are there Jetty calls to monitor or inspect this kind of internal state?